# How to create an Model using ADO.Net Entity Data Model

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, sql-server-2000, entity-model

I am new to ASP C#.Net. I need connect to the database from an ASP.Net application and display the fetched data. The issue is connecting to SQL Server 2000 from an ASP.NET MVC 5 Application.

DB Server(MS SQL Server 2000) connection was configured using an ODBC driver with user a DSN.

If I try to add an entity, it prompts me the following error. How do I create an entity and/or read from/to the database?

[Error MSG](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O5Ihj.jpg)

Greatly appreciate all your help in advance.

Comment: Any specific reason for using such an old instance of SQL server with MVC 5? Are you able to make a successful connection with the DB using the same connection string directly?

Comment: I need to work with existing older database, there is no option to upgrade it. I was able to connect to MS Sql 2000, using DataSet and ODBC connection by creating a system DSN.

Comment: Looked at your Error message. You may want to downgrade your MVC version to something lower. Putting this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25240192/entity-framework-6-supports-sql-server-2000) for your reference to spark some ideas.

Comment: Thanks RRM for the response, i did look through the link, i am not able to create an .edmx file to edit it. I will look into the MVC version. Thanks again.