# Connecting a sql server 2000 to visual studio 2015

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2015, sql-server-2000

I have a database on a remote server which is running with SQL server 8. Visual Studio 2015 has a new Entity framework version that is not backwards compatible (2005 or later is required). I read that there are workarounds to achieve a connection by editing the edmx file.
[Entity Framework 6 supports SQL Server 2000?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25240192/entity-framework-6-supports-sql-server-2000)

I start to created a new ADO.NET Entity Data Model(.edmx) and a wizard pops up. But in order to create the edmx file I need a connection with the database, which I cannot establish since an error is throws that I need 2005 or later. -.-

My Question is whether this is the right way and if it is, how do I achieve a connection?

Any suggestions, insights or further knowledge will help. Thanks.

edit: after some well meaning comments, I should specify that I have no choice but to use sql server 2000. I am also aware that sql server 8 is long discontinued.

Comment: So you want to know how to circumvent the connection to an unsuported version of SQL Server? I think you are begging for maintenance issues on the long run.

Comment: It's *five years*, since SQL Server 2000 fell out of even *extended* support. It is far beyond the time when you should be contemplating undertaking any *new* work against such a system.

Comment: Pretty confident in saying that VS 2015 does not support SQL Server 2000; for the reason being that it was **completely unsupported** when  VS 2015 was released. I don't blame Microsoft for that either. Why *waste* their time making a product work for another product they don't support at all anymore. You're likely going to need to use an old (possibly unsupported) version of Visual Studio (2010 is probably going to be the most "recent" that will"), or upgrade your instance (which is going to be fun, as you can't upgrade directly from 2000 to 2012+ (you have to do 2000->2008->2012+)).